# Looking for a good way to read data from file in C

Tags: c, file

this is my first question in this site, and I've just started programming, please be patient with me.
I'm having some trouble with this code to read strings and intergers from a file, they are separated by a semicolon ";" and it starts with the number of lines. The file is something like this:

```
13;
A;15;B;1;0;0;0;
A;9;C;0;3;2;0;
A;9;D;0;4;0;2;
A;3;E;2;3;2;0;
A;7;F;5;5;3;1;
A;5;G;5;7;6;0;
A;13;H;0;0;0;0;
A;1;I;8;1;0;0;
A;1;J;2;2;1;0;
A;6;K;7;3;2;0;
A;5;L;2;4;3;0;
A;12;AA;0;3;2;0;
A;9;BA;0;1;0;0;
```

What I tried to do was to create a function that would receive a file pointer (fp) and the number of lines that was read in the main function. It would read the file and save the intergers and strings in matrices :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char timesjogos[100][2][100];
int golsjogos[100][3];
int faltasjogos[100][3];
int camajogos[100][3];
int cverjogos[100][3];

int ReadGames(FILE *caminho,int njogos){
    printf("starting to read jogos.\n");
    int i=0;
    while(fscanf(caminho, " %[^;];%d[^;];%[^;];%d[^;];%d[^;];%d[^;];%d[^;];",
        timesjogos[i][0], &golsjogos[i][0], timesjogos[i][1], &golsjogos[i][1],
        &faltasjogos[i][0], &camajogos[i][0], &cverjogos[i][0]) == 7)
   {
        if(i < njogos)
            i++;
        else
            break;
    }    
}

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int nbets;
    fp = fopen("jogos.txt", "r");
    if (!fp){
        printf ("Error trying to open file.");
    }
    fscanf(fp, " %d[^;];", &nbets);
    ReadGames(fp, nbets);
}
```

My doubts are about the %[^;]; I used to read each string up to the ;  , should I use %d[^;] for the intergers? What is the correct way to do it?

Also, I'm using global variables to save the information read, the problem is that they can be not large enough to save huge amounts of lines (my professor made a 24180 lines file to test our codes). I was thinking about using the number of lines it gives in the first line to make pre-sized matrices inside the function, but how can I return or save it after the function ends?

I'm sorry for the huge code, but I wanted to show all the details. I would be very thankful for your more experienced help :D

Comment: Try std::getline(string, ';').

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: When did `std::getline` become available in C?

Comment: I need to store the intergers and strings separately, will this store the whole line?

Comment: It would help to know precisely what you are supposed to do with the integers and the strings. Store them in separate files? Under which format? Since I can't read your language (Spanish?), I can hardly get that information from your source file :)

Comment: "My doubts are about" - did you try compiling and running your code? What happens when you do? Does it compile? Does it run? Does it read the correct values into the correct arrays? You can create a smaller version of the file for your initial tests, and then move up to the real one when you have it working on the small one.

Comment: I'm supposed to read them from the file and store it in a way that I can access it later, knowing which ones are the strings and the intergers. Each one of them has a different meaning, that's why I was trying to store them in separated matrices inside the code. The code was in Portuguese, I'll try to translate it better. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @KenWhite The OP has tagged the question as C++ so all's fair.

Comment: @Thomas: It was gone when I posted my comment. :-) Besides, the code is clearly C and not C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%[^;]` notation reads a string consisting of any number of non-semicolons.  The parsing stops when a semicolon is encountered.  With numbers, the parsing stops at a semicolon anyway; the semicolon is not a part of the representation of a number.

Your use of `%d[^;]` means that `fscanf()` is looking for an integer (`%d`), then an open square bracket, caret, semicolon and close square bracket.  These don't appear in the input, of course, so the scanning fails.

Therefore, your input loop should probably be:

```
while (fscanf(caminho, " %[^;];%d;%[^;];%d;%d;%d;%d;",
              timesjogos[i][0], &golsjogos[i][0], timesjogos[i][1],
              &golsjogos[i][1], &faltasjogos[i][0], &camajogos[i][0],
              &cverjogos[i][0]) == 7)
{
    ...
}
```

You might prefer to specify a maximum length for the `%[^;]` conversion specifications; `%99[^;]` would be appropriate since the third dimension of `timesjogos` is 100.  There's an off-by-one difference between the length specified and the length used (enshrined because of ancient history; it was that way before the first C standard, and the C standard codified existing practice).

Comment: So, the %[^;] will read everything as a string? Or will the vector's type determine if it's a string or an interger? Thanks for answering so fast btw.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the vector's type", but `%[xyz]` is a conversion specification that reads a string (in this example, consisting of the letters x, y or z).  It is just like `%s` except that you get to specify which characters are OK.  When you write `%d[^;]`, you have _one_ conversion specification (`%d`) followed by four characters which, since they are not preceded by a `%`, are not part of a conversion specification  and therefore stand for themselves; the characters must appear in the input for the scanning to proceed past this point in the format string.